# Website scraping and screenshots

Tags: python, scrapy, screenshot

I am scrapping a website using [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/) and storing the internal/external links in my items class.

Is there a way that when the link is scrapped, I can capture the screenshot of it  ?

Note : the website has a login authorisation form.

My Code (spider.py)

```
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
  from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
  from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
  from tutorial.items import DmozItem
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
  import urlparse
  from scrapy import log

  class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

      items = []
      failed_urls = []
      duplicate_responses = []

      name = 'myspiders'
      allowed_domains = ['someurl.com']
      login_page = 'someurl.com/login_form'
      start_urls = 'someurl.com/'

      rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=('logged_out', 'logout',)), follow=True, callback='parse_start_url')]

      def start_requests(self):

          yield Request(
              url=self.login_page,
              callback=self.login,
              dont_filter=False
              )


      def login(self, response):
          """Generate a login request."""
          return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formnumber=1,
            formdata={'username': 'username', 'password': 'password' },
            callback=self.check_login_response)


      def check_login_response(self, response):
          """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are
          successfully logged in.
          """
          if "Logout" in response.body:
              self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling! :%s" % response, level=log.INFO)
              self.log("Response Url : %s" % response.url, level=log.INFO)

              yield Request(url=self.start_urls)
          else:
              self.log("Bad times :(", loglevel=log.INFO)


      def parse_start_url(self, response):


          # Scrape data from page
          hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

          self.log('response came in from : %s' % (response), level=log.INFO)

          # check for some important page to crawl
          if response.url == 'someurl.com/medical/patient-info' :

              self.log('yes I am here', level=log.INFO)

              urls = hxs.select('//a/@href').extract()
              urls = list(set(urls))


              for url in urls :

                  self.log('URL extracted : %s' % url, level=log.INFO)

                  item = DmozItem()

                  if response.status == 404 or response.status == 500:
                      self.failed_urls.append(response.url)
                      self.log('failed_url : %s' % self.failed_urls, level=log.INFO)
                      item['failed_urls'] = self.failed_urls

                  else :

                      if url.startswith('http') :
                          if url.startswith('someurl.com'):
                              item['internal_link'] = url

                              # Need to capture screenshot of the extracted url here

                              self.log('internal_link :%s' % url, level=log.INFO)
                          else :
                              item['external_link'] = url

                              # Need to capture screenshot of the extracted url here

                              self.log('external_link :%s' % url, level=log.INFO)

                  self.items.append(item)

              self.items = list(set(self.items))
              return self.items
          else :
              self.log('did not recieved expected response', level=log.INFO)
```

**Update** : I am using a Virtual Machine (logged-in through putty)

Answer (score 5):

You can look at a rendering server like [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash)

Comment: is it possible to use selenium to take screenshots of the scrapped urls (also the authenticated ones) in my code ?